Trouble Applying Customized Configuration Settings in Postgres
I have a question regarding configurations optimization in Postgres 17. I have coded for optimized configurations. For most of the parameters, the settings get applied except for effective cache size, wal buffers, and shared buffers.I check the settings with:
sudo docker exec -it postgres psql -U user -d postgres -c "SELECT name, setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name IN ( 'shared_buffers', 'effective_cache_size', 'work_mem', 'maintenance_work_mem', 'archive_mode', 'archive_command', 'wal_buffers', 'checkpoint_completion_target', 'max_wal_size', 'max_worker_processes', 'max_parallel_workers_per_gather', 'effective_io_concurrency', 'synchronous_commit', 'autovacuum_max_workers', 'autovacuum_naptime', 'max_connections' );"I receive the following output:
shared_buffers = 5GB effective_cache_size = 15GB work_mem = 128MB maintenance_work_mem = 2GB archive_mode=on archive_command = 'cp %p /var/lib/postgresql/wal_archive/%f' wal_buffers = 16MB checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9 max_wal_size = 4GB max_worker_processes = 4 max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2 effective_io_concurrency = 4 synchronous_commit = on autovacuum_max_workers = 3 autovacuum_naptime = 30s max_connections = 20This translates to:

archive_command: cp %p /var/lib/postgresql/wal_archive/%f- OKAY

archive_mode: on - OKAY

autovacuum_max_workers: 3 - OKAY

autovacuum_naptime: 30 - OKAY

checkpoint_completion_target: 0.9 - OKAY

effective_cache_size: 1966080 (which is ~1.9GB)  - PROBLEM (should be 15GB)

effective_io_concurrency: 4 - OKAY

maintenance_work_mem: 2097152 (which is 2GB) - OKAY

max_connections: 20 - OKAY

max_parallel_workers_per_gather: 2 - OKAY

max_wal_size: 4096 (which is 4GB) - OKAY

max_worker_processes: 4 - OKAY

shared_buffers: 655360 (which is ~640MB) - PROBLEM (should be 5GB)

synchronous_commit: on - OKAY

wal_buffers: 2048 (which is 2MB) - PROBLEM (should be 16MB)

work_mem: 131072 (which is 128MB) - OKAY
Summary of Issues:

effective_cache_size: Needs to be set to 15GB.

shared_buffers: Needs to be set to 5GB.

wal_buffers: Needs to be set to 16MB


I have attempted to convert GB/MB to bytes and integers, but still have no success. Any idea how this should be done properly?
Converting from GB to integers and bytes.

shared_buffers: 655360 Each buffer is 8kB, that's 5GB in total
